# Angular 8 - How to handle error response?

Tags: angular

I don't get anything in response if an error is thrown from WEB API. but get a response in case of success and debugger hits.

I just want to receive an error response and debugger should be hit always whether an error is thrown or a success message is sent from the web API.

```
   this.dataService.post(this.defaultURL + "changepassword", myObject ).subscribe(result => {
          debugger // this is not hitting in case of error. 
          const res = result;
        });

    // Data Service contain HTTP post method. and i tested all three shown below. 
    // post 1 
    post(url: string, body: string): Observable<any> {
      return this.httpClient.post<Response>(url, body);
    }

    // post 2
      post(url: string, body): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post<Response>(url, body).pipe(catchError(error => {
          return this.handleError(of(error.error));
        } ));
      }

    // post 3
    post(url: string, body): Observable<any> {
      return this.httpClient.post<Response>(url, body).pipe(catchError(error => {
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
         return this.handleError(of(error.error));
      } ));
    } 


    handleError(error) {
      debugger

      let errorMessage = '';
      if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
          // client-side error
          errorMessage = `Error: ${error.error.message}`;
      } else {
          // server-side error
          errorMessage = `Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`;
      }
      console.log(errorMessage);
      return throwError(errorMessage);
    }
```

**API**

```
[HttpPost("changepassword")]
public IActionResult ChangePassword([FromBody] ChangePasswordViewModel changePasswordModel)
{        
   if (_identityAdapter.ChangePassword( changePasswordModel.OldPassword, changePasswordModel.NewPassword))
         return Ok("Password has been updated successfully");
   return BadRequest();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you can do to handle your error response easily.

`Observables` objects in angular have the following observers:

1. Next: **Required**. A handler for each delivered value. Called zero or more times after execution starts.
2. Error: **Optional**. A handler for an error notification. An error halts execution of the observable instance.
3. Complete: **Optional**. A handler for the execution-complete notification. Delayed values can continue to be delivered to the next handler after execution is complete.

Let's suppose you have one post service.

**Service.ts**

```
  add(offer: any): Observable<any> {
     return this.httpClient.post(API_URL + 'offers', offer);
  }
```

**Component.ts**

```
    this.service.add(offerToSend).subscribe(
      next => {
           // Code 
      },
      error => {
        //Catching error
      },
      () => {
        //Success Response
      }
  );
```

**UPDATE:**

Based on your comments, here's what you can do:

**Service.ts**

```
add(object: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient
    .post(API_URL + 'notifications', object).catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: Response | any) {
  console.error('NotificationService::handleError', error);
  return Observable.throw(error);
}
```

Using the above method in your `service.ts` will allow you to handle errors in `service` instead of `components`

Comment: yeah, it works now, but I want the above add method to handle the errors for me, as I would call it in different components. and I would keep it in a centralized service by the name post.

Comment: basically i do not want to write an error method in each web API call.

Comment: @NaveedUllahJlani Please check the update, add a private method to the `service` in which it handles the errors

Comment: a red line showing below .catch, and error is "Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Observable<Object>'"

Comment: Where are you importing the `Observable` from?

Comment: Try to add the following import please `import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';`

Comment: import { Observable} from 'rxjs';

Comment: Okay then try to import `catch` as I mentioned in my comment above

Comment: import { Observable } from  'rxjs/add/operator/catch' not working as says has no exported member.

Comment: add(url: string, body): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient
    .post(url + 'notifications', body) .pipe(catchError(this.handleError))
}  // this works, but what would i write after subscribing in component. should i also mention     error => {
        } as without it I am not getting error in the component.

Comment: in the component after subscribing error, the debugger is hit after error, but the exact error is not shown but I am getting proper error in console.

Comment: Please update your question with the new code and explain more, you're not making yourself clear